# Appropriate linear mixed-effects model for hierarchical data?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear-model

We have some hypothetical data for the abundance of a protein that accumulates in cells with age.

The goal is to run a linear mixed model to test how much of the variation in the rate at which cells accumulate this protein is explained by differences in the lifespan between species. For example do the cells in long lived elephants accumulate the protein at a slower rate than short lived mice?

For multiple animals of different ages we have measured the abundance of the protein from multiple independent cells. I've run a basic linear mixed model but am not sure how to correctly incorporate the nested hierarchical nature of the data (i.e. that we have cells sampled from animals that are sampled from different species).

The data:

```
Protein_count   Sample  Age_years   Species Lifespan_years  Protein_count_per_year
55  mouse_1 0.5 mouse   2   110
60  mouse_1 0.5 mouse   2   120
50  mouse_1 0.5 mouse   2   100
49  mouse_1 0.5 mouse   2   98
101 mouse_2 1   mouse   2   101
110 mouse_2 1   mouse   2   110
98  mouse_2 1   mouse   2   98
104 mouse_2 1   mouse   2   104
206 mouse_3 2   mouse   2   103
190 mouse_3 2   mouse   2   95
230 mouse_3 2   mouse   2   115
212 mouse_3 2   mouse   2   106
80  mink_1  4   mink    8   20
88  mink_1  4   mink    8   22
90  mink_1  4   mink    8   22.5
108 mink_1  4   mink    8   27
180 mink_2  7   mink    8   25.71428571
184 mink_2  7   mink    8   26.28571429
175 mink_2  7   mink    8   25
38  tiger_1 5   tiger   20  7.6
44  tiger_1 5   tiger   20  8.8
55  tiger_1 5   tiger   20  11
50  tiger_1 5   tiger   20  10
163 tiger_2 15  tiger   20  10.86666667
145 tiger_2 15  tiger   20  9.666666667
155 tiger_2 15  tiger   20  10.33333333
152 tiger_2 15  tiger   20  10.13333333
89  elephant_1  30  elephant    60  2.966666667
97  elephant_1  30  elephant    60  3.233333333
112 elephant_1  30  elephant    60  3.733333333
104 elephant_1  30  elephant    60  3.466666667
204 elephant_2  58  elephant    60  3.517241379
187 elephant_2  58  elephant    60  3.224137931
199 elephant_2  58  elephant    60  3.431034483
184 elephant_2  58  elephant    60  3.172413793
180 elephant_2  58  elephant    60  3.103448276
```

Definition of headers:

```
Protein_count = abundance of the protein measured in a cell
Sample = ID of animal from which cells are taken
Age_years = age of the sampled animal
Species = the species of the animal
Lifespan_years = lifespan of the species
Protein_count_per_year = protein abundance adjusted by sample age to give a rate of protein accumulation per year (Protein_count_per_year = Protein_count/Age_years)
```

I've done a simple linear mixed-effect model like this:

```
mixed.lmer <- lmer(Protein_count_per_year ~ Lifespan_years + (1|Species), data = species_data)
```

However I think I should be taking a few more things into account:

1) There are hierarchical relationships in the data. For example there is hierarchical nesting between sample and species. Should I be doing something like this to take that into account:

```
  + (1|Species/Sample)
```

or

```
+ (1|Sample) + (1|Species:animal)
```

I'm not sure which formulation is correct.

2) We think that the protein abundance starts at 0 when each animal is born and increases linearly with age, but we want to know if the rate of accumulation varies with species and is explained by lifespan. So I think we would want to fix the intercept at 0 and add a random slope?

Please let me know if I can be more clear in my question. I really appreciate any feedback or suggestions. Thanks in advance!